# Determining the best possible substitution for an integrand

Tags: calculus

What substitution is best used to calculate  $$\int \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{x^2 -1}}dx$$

Comment: Have you got a worse case already?

Comment: [These](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) are not necessarily the best in length, but are definitely the ones every student should know.

Answer (score 6):

The quadratic form suggests $x = \sec\theta$.  But rationalizing first gives
$$
\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{x^2-1}} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-1}{x^2} 
$$
Now substituting $x=\sec\theta$ yields (after some algebra)
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-1}{x^2}\,dx = \int(\sec\theta - \cos\theta - \sin\theta)\,d\theta
$$

Comment: Teaching only trigonometric substitutions creates students that can't solve all the integrals of this type. Which is a shame for math teachers, given that these integrals belong to the realm of (easy) algorithmically solvable integrals.

Comment: Instead of complaining and bashing another post, @Pp.., you are free to answer yourself.

Comment: @amWhy I already did! My comment was very necessary, given that he teaches the next generation precisely this topic.

Comment: @Pp.. Do you have something you think is a better idea to do with this "easy algorithmically solvable integral"? If you do please do post a comment or an answer.

Comment: @Timbuc Do you have anything to say that makes sense? If you do, do it. Otherwise look at the very first idea the OP was given since the post was open.

Comment: @Pp.. You only posted a link to general Euler's substitution and determined "every student should know these", with which I agree, but the question is: in **this case**, is that better than the given option? If it is prove it, otherwise it looks like you're simply bashing, as usual, other people's efforts to help.

Comment: @Timbuc A solution can be better in length, or it can be better in depth. Education has more or less preserved in common culture that integrals of rational functions can be solved using something called partial fraction decomposition. Through the years many bad text books, and bad teachers, have injected into common knowledge that these integral go with trigonometric substitutions. Which of course, is a mistake. This is why you see so many students not knowing how to begin. Compare that with rational functions, for which they may not know how to finish.

Answer (score 6):

@Pp. suggests an [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) of the form
\begin{align*}
x  &= \frac{t^2+1}{2t} = \frac{t}{2} + \frac{1}{2t} \\
dx &= \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2t^2}\right)\,dt = \frac{t^2-1}{2t^2}\,dt 
\end{align*}

> By this method you gain being able to solve **all** integrals of this type: Additions, multiplications and divisions of the square root of a quadratic polynomial and $x$.

Then
\begin{align}
x^2 - 1 &= \frac{t^4+2t^2+1}{4t^2} - \frac{4t^2}{4t^2} \\
        &= \frac{t^4-2t^2+1}{4t^2} = \left(\frac{t^2-1}{2t}\right)^2
\end{align}
So the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx
&= \int\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{t^2-1}{2t}} \left(\frac{t^2-1}{2t^2}\right)\,dt\\
&= \int\frac{t^2-1}{t(t^2+2t-1)}\,dt
\end{align*}

> The result of the Euler substitution is the integral of a rational function, which can always be solved by using their partial fraction decomposition.

In this case the denominator splits into linear factors.
$$
\frac{t^2-1}{t(t^2+2t-1)} = \frac{A}{t} + \frac{B}{t+1-\sqrt{2}} + \frac{C}{t+1+\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: (I think your solution using trig substitution is simpler, though.)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious substitution when dealing with expressions of the form $\sqrt{x^2\pm a^2}$ is either $x=a\sinh t$ $($for $+)$ or $x=a\cosh t$ $($for $-)$. Then use $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1,~$ along with $\sinh't=\cosh t~$ and $~\cosh't=\sinh t$.

Comment: In some cases, an additional substitution of the form $u=e^{~\large t}$ might be in order, reducing the new integrand to a rational function.